# Wordpress Query two weeks back

Tags: mysql, wordpress

The following query goes back one week but how would I make it so it goes back two:

```
$columnists=new WP_Query(array('showposts'=>3, 'cat'=>66622, 'orderby'=>'rand','w'=>date('W'),'year'=>date('Y')));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this

```
'w'=>date('W')-1
```

instead of

```
'w'=>date('W')
```

If it doasn't work here is the documentation of WP_Query function
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query